# intent.putExtra() for multiple textboxes

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to modify an Android app to suit my need.
The original app has page 1 to display list of notes, and page 2 displays the detailed note.
What I'm trying to achieve is instead of having only 1 textbox in the detailed note page, I want it to have several textboxes, and persist it as well.

Here is how I thought it would be (but failed miserably of course).
This the transmitter on the page 2 (detailed page) activity:

```
private void saveAndFinish()
{
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventTitle);
String eventTitle = et.getText().toString();

EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventDate);
String eventDate = et2.getText().toString();

EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventVenue);
String eventVenue = et3.getText().toString();

EditText et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventLocation);
String eventLocation = et4.getText().toString();

EditText et5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventNote);
String eventNote = et5.getText().toString();

EditText et6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventAttendees);
String eventAttendees = et6.getText().toString();


Intent intent = new Intent();
// pass these to the main activity will ya?
intent.putExtra("key", data.getKey());
intent.putExtra("title", eventTitle); // eventTitle is the edited text!
intent.putExtra("date", eventDate); 
intent.putExtra("venue", eventVenue); 
intent.putExtra("location", eventLocation); 
intent.putExtra("note", eventNote); 
intent.putExtra("attendees", eventAttendees); 

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
// work done, go back to calling activity
finish();
}
```

This the receiver on the page 1 (main page) activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (requestCode==DETAIL_ACTIVITY_REQ && resultCode==RESULT_OK) 
    {
        DataItem event = new DataItem();
        event.setKey(data.getStringExtra("key"));
        event.setTitle(data.getStringExtra("title"));
        event.setDate(data.getStringExtra("date"));
        event.setVenue(data.getStringExtra("venue"));
        event.setLocation(data.getStringExtra("location"));
        event.setNote(data.getStringExtra("note"));
        event.setAttendees(data.getStringExtra("attendees"));

    datasource.update(event);
    refreshDisplay();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    // which list view item was selected?
    DataItem data = eventsList.get(position);

    //now, to navigate. which class should i go to next?
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailedActivity.class); 
    // and also, pass data to the next activity will ya?
    intent.putExtra("key", data.getKey());
    intent.putExtra("title", data.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("date", data.getDate());
    intent.putExtra("venue", data.getVenue());
    intent.putExtra("location", data.getLocation());
    intent.putExtra("note", data.getNote());
    intent.putExtra("attendees", data.getAttendees());
    // go go go!
    startActivityForResult(intent, DETAIL_ACTIVITY_REQ);
}
```

Apparently only the "title" is saved, everything else is not. Help?

Comment: Do you want to post the receiving code too?

Comment: oops... done! added the receiver.

Comment: Did you try to use Bundle instead of passing them with the Intent extras?

Comment: Your problem is that your intent has not all the information you want, right?

Comment: yes, apparently only the "title" with the corresponding "key" is saved correctly. everything else is just filled with "title".

Comment: I am trying with Bundle now @Pavlos

Answer (score 0):

modify your code in saveAndFinish method

Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivityname.this,secondActivityname.class);

startActivity(intent);

Above code is put data and send to second activity.

now get above data in second activity

Intent intent = getIntent();

String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");

String date = intent.getStringExtra("date");

String venue = intent.getStringExtra("venue");

String location = intent.getStringExtra("location");

String note = intent.getStringExtra("note");

String attendees = intent.getStringExtra("attendees");

Answer (score 0):

You must use getIntent() to get the data from Intent:

```
data = getIntent();
```

use on ActivityResult:

```
data = getIntent();
```

Comment: I know I have edited this answer but this answer is still incomplete! Include more and correct detail.

Comment: When you pass the data from intent then u must get it data from getIntent method.you want to write the data = getIntent() in your onActivityResult method